# Visual Studio copy dependent projects

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

i have a main project `A` which uses a library project `B`.

But since `B` is used via dependency injection (loaded via reflection) it is not in the references of `A` and Visual Studio does not automatically copy the binaries and data of `B` to the bin directory of `A`.

is there a way to accomplish this without making a huge post-build-event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If project `B` binary is only used by project `A` then you could change the build property of project `B` to always copy the output binary to bin folder of project `A`

To change the out put path go to Project Property > Build > Output path:

[image]